# Comand "mongod --auth --bind_ip_all" running infinitely and consuming too much RAM - Mongo with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I have this comand **mongod --auth --bind_ip_all** running infinitely and consuming too much RAM in my server, what does mean? And what i can do to fix it? I'm running mongo on docker in Ubuntu.

When i run netstat command it shows this:

tcp6  0  0 localhost:25010 localhost:38388 ESTABLISHED
tcp6  0  0 localhost:25010 localhost:34014 ESTABLISHED
tcp6  0  0 localhost:25010 localhost:57152 ESTABLISHED
tcp6  0  0 localhost:25010 localhost:46990 ESTABLISHED
tcp6  0  0 localhost:25010 localhost:48236 ESTABLISHED

[image]

Comment: Well, you launched MongoDB and it's running. If you don't need it, don't launch it.

Comment: Considere to read about the mongod https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/

Answer (score 0):

I'll take care of it in the meantime：

```
docker restart mongodb
```